# How do I remove my own filterby or sortby pages from Google Search?

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, url, google-index

My site has filterby and sortby pages that appear in Google Search and I want to delete them from Google. Such as:

```
http://example.com/product-category/desktop-computers/?filter_hard-drive-type=hard-disk-drive-hdd&filter_ram-capacity=ram-size-16-gb&filtering=1&filter_rating=
```

I have used the Google URL Parameters, but didn't seem to work. My orderby pages still show up in Google and I have done this a long time ago:

[image: URL Parameters]

I am using WooCommerce attributes to make these pages with WordPress.

Comment: Are you able to noindex these pages? If so, this is your best option.

Comment: No, I can't do that, these pages are based of an attribute from WooCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two solutions.

#### Use robots.txt

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: *filtering=1*
```

or maybe just `*filter*`

#### Use Search Console URL Parameters:

[Add the parameters to your Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en) account for the site.  In this case they are "active parameters" and you want to set Google to crawl "No URLs".  You can add the following parameters for that URL:

- `filter_hard-drive-type`
- `filter_ram-capacity`
- `filtering`
- `filter_rating`

If all your filter URLs use the `filtering` parameter, it should be enough to set just that one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same conclusion, this section of the search console seems to be useless.

If those url are still reachable but you no more use those url (url migration) it will be easy : just use a 410 gone in your htaccess file and google will remove them after few times.